# Spark RDD.foreach executing but not doing intended work

Tags: scala, apache-spark

this is my first question here, so be kind and let me know if I break any rules.

I am writing a sessionization job on s3 dump of events.
I have obtained through transformations an keypair RDD: `mainRDD = RDD[sessionId, List(events)]` where events is my case class.
My flow of code post the obtained RDD is as below:

`mainRDD.foreach( ...persistSessions...)`  *persisting sessions with processing list of events within session*

`val newRDD = mainRDD.map( _._2.filter( ...some filter... )  )` *applying some on filter on events within session*

`newRDD.collect().foreach( for loop on the list of events(
       persist filtered events on some logic on eventList
))`

The first foreach is working fine and my sessions are getting persisted
The second foreach is not. It is definitely running which I can see from the logs

`16/09/26 07:57:12 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 3 (foreach at BatchProcess.scala:60) finished in 0.176 s
16/09/26 07:57:12 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: foreach at BatchProcess.scala:60, took 0.226938 s`

but its getting finished quickly and the data is not getting persisted. there is no issue in the persistance logic, have double checked it.

Is there an issue in using for loop within the RDD.foreach? Is there a better alternative?

EDIT:
added code snippet: Sorry had to make it generic

```
// mainRDD definition
mainRDD[(String, List[events])]

// newRDD definition
newRDD = mainRDD.map[(String, Long, List[events])](x => 
(x._1,x._2.last.someEventProp ,x._2.filter(a => a.someEventProp == "filter logic")))

// foreach on newRDD
newRDD.foreach(f=> for(i <- 0 until f._3.length){
// calculating someVariable value 
  if(f._3(i).someEventProp != null) {
    someVar = f._3(i).someEventProp.getOrElse("someVar", "NA").toString
  } 

// persisting for complete loop except last element in eventList
if(i != f._3.length - 1) {
  persistData(f._3(i).someEventProp, f._3(i).someEventProp, f._3(i).someEventProp, f._3(i+1).someEventProp, someVar)
  } 
else {
// for last element in the list
  persistData(f._3(i).someEventProp, f._3(i).someEventProp, f._3(i).someEventProp, f._2, someVar)
  }
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see the actual code within that `foreach` block to be able to help you.

Comment: @asalia : what is that newRDD, is it Tuple? why do you want to collect then do foreach? is there any specific purpose? when you collect everything will be collected to driver node it means its running on single machine.

Comment: @cheseaux added the code snippet.

Comment: @Shankar I was trying different things, tried only foreach, then tried .collect().foreach...earlier did not look at the logs, just checked if it persisted or not..

Comment: What is `persistData` doing?

Comment: @Reactormonk its calling a persist method to save the data in sql database

Comment: Check the client logs, maybe they couldn't connect to the DB.

Comment: @Reactormonk Well checked and no such issue, the first foreach loop is also persisting in the same DB successfully

Comment: Is it that the rdd on which you call rdd.collect.foreach() is persisting the data but the rdd on which you do not call collect first is not persisting? Please confirm.

Comment: no, I had used rdd.foreach() for both persist calls earlier, where first one was persisting but second one was not.. later in hit and trial I changed the second one to rdd.collect().foreach().. which too did not work....

Comment: It finally worked, I changed the foreach call to a map transformation and called the persistence within the map.. Still don't know why foreach wasn't working.

Comment: @asalia  i'm facing the same issue ...i had the same exact experience as you ...but for spark application to run ...it need's an action along with transformation , so i'm forced to use foreach ..if you could please share what action u used along with map ..it will help out a lot...by the way its a great first question kudos for that !